# @JsonFormat not working with custom serializer

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, serialization

I have some special business that makes me need a custom serializer，it add a field to the field that modified the **DictAnnotation** annotation, It works.
But **@JsonFormat** not working.
My **createTime** field used to look like this：

```
"createTime":"2019-12-12"
```

now：

```
"createTime":1577835397615
```

The fields that are not modified by DictAnnotation have used the default JsonSerializer, so I don't know where the problem lies.

My main code is as follows:

bind custom SerializerModifier

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder() {
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
    SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule().setSerializerModifier(new DictSerializerModifier());
    builder.modules(simpleModule);
    return builder;
}
```

custome SerializerModifier

```
public class DictSerializerModifier extends Jdk8BeanSerializerModifier {
    @Override
    public JsonSerializer<?> modifySerializer(SerializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc, JsonSerializer<?> serializer) {
        return new DictSerializer(null, (JsonSerializer<Object>) serializer);
    }
}
```

custom Serializer

```
public class DictSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> implements ContextualSerializer {

    private static final String MY_BIZ_FIELD_SUFFIX = "_test";
    private DictAnnotation.ElementType type;
    private JsonSerializer<Object> defSerializer;

    public DictSerializer(DictAnnotation.ElementType type, JsonSerializer<Object> jsonSerializer) {
        this.defSerializer = jsonSerializer;
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public JsonSerializer<?> createContextual(SerializerProvider prov, BeanProperty property) {
        // my biz annotation
        DictAnnotation.ElementType elementType = Optional.ofNullable(property).map(b -> b.getAnnotation(DictAnnotation.class))
                .map(d -> d.type()).orElse(null);
        // if null, use defSerializer
        return elementType == null ? defSerializer : new DictSerializer(elementType, defSerializer);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        defSerializer.serialize(value, gen, serializers);
        if (type != null) {
            String fieldName = gen.getOutputContext().getCurrentName();
            String codeLabel = RedisUtils.dictCodeToLabel(type, value.toString());
            gen.writeStringField(fieldName.concat(MY_BIZ_FIELD_SUFFIX), codeLabel);
        }
    }
}
```

test pojo class

```
public class TestVo {

    @DictAnnotation(type = A)
    private String aCode;

    @DictAnnotation(type = B)
    private String bCode;

    @DictAnnotation(type = C)
    private String cCode;

    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd",timezone = "GMT+8")
    private Date createTime;  
getter.... settter...
```

Looking forward to your guidance！

Comment: Why you extend `Jdk8BeanSerializerModifier `? Could you try `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerModifier` instead? Maybe `Jdk8BeanSerializerModifier` does more than you want.

Comment: Did you return the `TestVo` as a HTTP response with `@ResponseBody` in Spring Boot 1.X?

Comment: @Michał Ziober After trying, the effect is the same. It seems that Jdk8BeanSerializerModifier also extends BeanSerializerModifier, but only optimizes some details.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try if that helps (adding @JsonSerialize like mentioned below)

```
@JsonSerialize(as = Date.class)
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
private Date createTime;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is `JavaTimeModule` you can see [docs here](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-modules-java8/javadoc/datetime/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/JavaTimeModule.html)

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder() {
  Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
  SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule().setSerializerModifier(new DictSerializerModifier());
  builder.modules(simpleModule, new JavaTimeModule());
  return builder;
}
```

This module can help to add many default serialize and deserialize way for date time data type.